# Scraping links from buttons on a page

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape the links from the "box score" button on this [page](http://www.espn.com/nfl/scoreboard/_/year/2016/seasontype/1/week/2). The button is supposed to look like this

```
http://www.espn.com/nfl/boxscore?gameId=400874795
```

I tried to use this code to see if I could access the buttons but I cannot.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'http://www.espn.com/nfl/scoreboard/_/year/2016/seasontype/1/week/2'

advanced = url
r = requests.get(advanced)
data = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data,"html.parser")

for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    print link
```

Comment: 1) Download and inspect the raw HTML of the page; 2) Find the elements you want to scrape; 3) Write Python code searching for these elements; 4) ??? 5) Profit!

Comment: The problem here is that the html that you get back from the url isn't actually the page that you see when you view it in browser. There are a lot of ajax calls made to populate the page, so when you make the initial request, that data isn't there yet

Answer (score 2):

As wpercy mentions in his comment, you can't do this using `requests`, as a suggestion you should use **[`selenium`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/)** together with [**`Chromedriver`**](https://www.google.com.br/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiL49rg2rnVAhULG5AKHUZVACsQFggnMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fsites.google.com%2Fa%2Fchromium.org%2Fchromedriver%2Fdownloads&usg=AFQjCNEXjjDW0c8-GtJdUoc8wsRy0dEmpg)/[`PhantomJS`](http://phantomjs.org/download.html) for handling the JavaScript:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://www.espn.com/nfl/scoreboard/_/year/2016/seasontype/1/week/2"
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get(url)
html = browser.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')

boxList = soup.findAll('a',{'name':'&lpos=nfl:scoreboard:boxscore'})
```

All score buttons's `a` tag have the attribute `name = &lpos=nfl:scoreboard:boxscore`, so we first use `.findAll` and now a simple list comprehension can extract each `href` attribute:

```
>>> links = [box['href'] for box in boxList]
>>> links
['/nfl/boxscore?gameId=400874795', '/nfl/boxscore?gameId=400874854', '/nfl/boxscore?gameId=400874753', '/nfl/boxscore?gameId=400874757', '/nfl/boxscore?gameId=400874772', '/nfl/boxscore?gameId=400874777', '/nfl/boxscore?gameId=400874767', '/nfl/boxscore?gameId=400874812', '/nfl/boxscore?gameId=400874761', '/nfl/boxscore?gameId=400874764', '/nfl/boxscore?gameId=400874781', '/nfl/boxscore?gameId=400874796', '/nfl/boxscore?gameId=400874750', '/nfl/boxscore?gameId=400873867', '/nfl/boxscore?gameId=400874775', '/nfl/boxscore?gameId=400874798']
```

Answer (score 0):

here is the solution i did , and it scrapes all the link which are there on the url you have provided in your answer . you can check it out

```
# from BeautifulSoup import *
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
# import requests
import urllib
url = 'http://www.espn.com/nfl/scoreboard/_/year/2016/seasontype/1/week/2'

# advanced = url
html = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
# r = requests.get(html)
# data = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

tags = soup('a')

# for link in soup.find_all('a'):
for i,tag in enumerate(tags):
    # print tag;
    print i;
    ans = tag.get('href',None)
    print ans;
    print "\n";
```

Comment: This doesn't get the links from the "box score" buttons. That is what I need

Answer (score 0):

The answer from Gopal Chitalia didn't work for me, so I decided to post the working one (for python 3.6.5)

```
# from BeautifulSoup import *
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
# import requests
import urllib
url = 'http://www.espn.com/nfl/scoreboard/_/year/2016/seasontype/1/week/2'

# advanced = url
html = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
# urlopen(url).read()
# r = requests.get(html)
# data = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

tags = soup('a')

# for link in soup.find_all('a'):
for i,tag in enumerate(tags):
    # print tag;
    print (i);
    ans = tag.get('href',None)
    print (ans);
    print ("\n");
```

Comment: ah... and by the way, linter says there is no need to use semicolons in the end of the "print" lines